# Decoding and Encoding Double value in Python

Tags: python, pyspark, encoding, decoding

I would like to encode a double value like this:

```
DF1=spark.sql(f"""SELECT base64(aes_encrypt(bin(3.5),"123456789yxcvbnm")) as m""")
k=DF1.first()['m']
```

Now I want to decode this value, but it returns me the other value:

```
DF2=spark.sql(f"""SELECT float(string(aes_decrypt(unbase64("{k}"),"123456789yxcvbnm"))) as m2""")
DF2.first()['m2'] //It returns me 11!!!
```

What is my failure here? how can I decode this value correctly?

Comment: spark.sql's `bin()` turns an integer into a string representing that integer in binary - so it drops the fractional part, and turns `3` into `"11"`, which is not at all what you need here.  I think that would be `binary()`, although I'm not sure if `float()` is the right function to reverse the transformation.

Comment: @jasonharper `binary()` doesnt work in my code. Do you know any other alternative?

Comment: Why are you converting to binary in the first place? `SELECT base64(aes_encrypt("3.5","123456789yxcvbnm")) as m` would suffice, no? And then decrypting with `SELECT aes_decrypt(unbase64("{k}"),"123456789yxcvbnm") as m2`

Comment: in this example, it is enough, but in real world I would like to encrypt a column of a table which has `double`as data type

Comment: `aes_encrypt(string(<yourcolumn>), "123456789yxcvbnm") as m` would do the trick. I've not tried to encrypt a double typed column, perhaps the cast to string isn't even necessary. I feel like you've headed down a rabbit hole to solve a problem that may not exist. I'm no spark expert though and may be way off base, but it seems pretty straightforward.